# File scanning function is not usable

Tags: php, file-io

I've been making a function to scan files in a directory and scan for a specific file in the one of the folders in the scanned directory. To put it in simple terms,

Scanned Director -> Scan Folder in Director for specific file

Here's the code I've been using.

```
function __construct(){
$name = array_diff(scandir($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/"), array('..', '.'));
foreach($name as $key)
{
    $this->installed = array($key);
    while($this->check($key)){}
}
}

function check($name){
if(file_exists($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/".$name."/index.php"))
{
    echo "YES";
}
else
{
    echo "NO";
}
}
```

but the output returns "NO" even if the file is already in the folder. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/".$name."/index.php"` to make sure you're looking for the right file in the right folder?

Comment: array_diff returns an array. In your case, 

    $name = array_diff(scandir($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/"), array('..', '.'));

$name variable has an array now.

And in this line, 

    if(file_exists($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/".$name."/index.php"))
you are using the same variable concatenated with a string.

Comment: I am looking for the right file in the right folder... every folder has an index.php and still it doesn't output YES and I've used foreach function to change the array to strings...

Comment: You use `$name` in your string, but `$name` comes from `array_diff` that returns an array - **not** a string. It's probably trying to find `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT/apps/Array/index.php`, as `(string)array()` is `Array`.

Comment: @HaikalIzzuddin If you include `var_dump($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/".$name."/index.php")` as the first thing in `check()` can you then confirm that the paths are OK?

Comment: the paths are ok... its returning what I need... just when I want to confirm if the file index.php is in the folder its returns NO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below points again and proceed.

- Please check the file path
- Your folder and file must have permission to read.
- file_exists($filename) function will return FALSE for symlinks pointing to non-existing files.
- Your $name variable returns an array you have  used that in the file_exists($filename)
- I have made some modification in the code and i have checked its working fine here.

  ```
  $name = array_diff(scandir($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/"), array('..', '.'));
  foreach($name as $key) {
  $this->installed = array($key);
  while($this->check($key)){}
                if(file_exists($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/".$key."/index.php")){
      echo "YES";
  }else{
      echo "NO";
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes it will check all the Folder inside the apps/ folder.